# Can I avoid writing boilerplate code for classes that derive from an interface?

Tags: inheritance, interface, f#, boilerplate

I have many classes that implement an interface. Whenever I define a class I have to write something like this within the class definition:

```
interface Model.IModel with

        member this.Assets          = modelArg.Assets
        member this.AuxData         = modelArg.AuxData
        member this.Benchmark       = modelArg.Benchmark
        member this.CalcPeriods     = modelArg.CalcPeriods
        member this.CashTicker      = modelArg.CashTicker
        member this.Description     = modelArg.Description
        member this.FirstValidDate  = modelArg.FirstValidDate
        member this.Name            = modelArg.Name
        member this.ParamData       = modelArg.ParamData
        member this.ParamList       = modelArg.ParamList
        member this.Strategy        = modelArg.Strategy

        member this.CalcStartTime with get() = calcStartTime and
                                       set v = calcStartTime <- v

        member this.Counter with get() = counter and
                                 set v = counter <- v
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating this for each and every class that derives from the interface IModel? The code is identical in all cases.

Comment: A base class that implements the interface and the individual implementations inheriting from that base class is the only way I can think of. (I kind of suspect the more interesting part here is the larger context and purpose, because it might well be that an entirely different approach might be more idiomatic F#.)

Comment: Ok, but I believe inheritance is to be avoided, and I have been trying to do that. Actually with a base class there would be no need for an interface. If there is no other way I will do it. One of the reasons I have an interface is to have polymorphism. This would also work with a base class. Another way to implement polymorphism is with Discriminated Unions, but I would have to have one DU per method, I believe, so I reluctantly chose to go with classes and an interface.

Comment: Yes, avoiding classes and inheritance where possible is an important goal in F#, but it being a multiparadigm language, there will be cases where using "object programming", as Don Syme, calls it is necessary or simply the better way. But the things you mention are what I meant when I said the larger context would be the interesting thing here, because that might allow for getting to a completely different design decision. That would be a different question, though, I guess, and require seeing a lot more code that you might not be able to share.

Comment: I would not mind sharing the code but it would be to big and cumbersome. I will try to figure out a simple way to show what I am trying to do and put it in another question.

Comment: Why do you have to write this in every class?  Having a huge list of properties that you need to include everywhere seems like a massive design issue.

Comment: why can't you just provide a default implementation？

Comment: @TheInnerLight - You may be right, but I do not know how to do it in anoother way except if I create a super class and make my classes inherit from it, as suggested by `TeaDrivenDev` above. If that is not what you are suggesting please let me know. Maybe I should have explained that all those properties (like `modelArg.Assets`) come from the class constructor's single parameter `modelArg`. They are not the same object for different classes or even different instantiations of a class.

Comment: @s952163 - Please see my answer to `TheInnerLight's` comment.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you create a superclass that you inherit from.  There must be many other options.  One plausible option that I could imagine would be creating a single model type that performs all of this specific behaviour you need for some type within your domain model.

Without further information about your objective though, it's hard to suggest anything too concrete.

Comment: @TheInnerLight - I considered doing something like this when I started this project. However, instead of one Discriminated Union selecting a class I would have several DUs, one per method, each one selecting an implementation. That is perfectly OK, but it looked less convenient at the time. Now that the number of classes is increasing it does not look so clear which one would be the best alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the discussion a bit more concrete, and due to the limited space in the comments, something like the below would or would not work for you?

```
 type ModelArg = {
     Number: int
     Name: string
 }

 type IModel(modelArg: ModelArg) = 
    abstract member Number: int
    abstract member Name: string
    default __.Number = modelArg.Number
    default __.Name = modelArg.Name

type ConcreteModel1(modelArg: ModelArg) =
    inherit IModel(modelArg)

type ConcreteModel2(modelArg: ModelArg) =
    inherit IModel(modelArg)

let modelArg1 = {Number=2; Name ="Joe"}
let modelArg2 = {Number=3; Name = "Jim"}

let getNumberAndName(x: IModel) =
    (x.Number, x.Name)

let model1 = ConcreteModel1(modelArg1)
let model2 = ConcreteModel2(modelArg2)

getNumberAndName(model1)
//val it : int * string = (2, "Joe")
getNumberAndName(model2)
//val it : int * string = (3, "Jim")
```

Comment: Probably. I will try it. Three basic questions: 1) The Microsoft docs say the `default` keyword "Indicates an implementation of an abstract method; used together with an abstract method declaration to create a virtual method." But in this case the `default` is an abstract member, not an abstract method. Is this Ok?  2) Could one just *not* have Number and Name as abstract in your example? If yes, is there an advantage of having them as abstract? 3) I have three abstract methods in my classes. Would I have to annotate the base class with `[<AbstractClass>]`?

Comment: @Soldalma 1. Yes. 2. Yes, you could just create a type that holds the logic you need, and pass it as a constructor argument ala dependency injection, then expose the whole type as property and operate on it. The second part of your question is related to. 3. The advantage of using an abstract class would be that you could mix implemented and not-implemented members. You can also override those in a later implementation. I believe you will need to annotate with `[<AbstractClass>]` if you provide abstract members without the default implementation.

Comment: Ok, it worked. Lots of boilerplate eliminated. Thanks.